# Is there any convenient way to do the debugging for Spark program?

Tags: apache-spark

When I doing the homework of our class with my partner, I found his program using spark has problem when executing:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext

import scala.math.random

object PropertyInvestmentCalcs {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("spark://xxxxxx").setAppName("ID2015012134")

    val spark = new SparkContext(conf)


    //val rdd = spark.textFile("/home/Zhejing/Programs/Benchmarks/src/dataset/salaryEx.csv")
    val rdd = spark.textFile("/User/2015012134/Hw5/salary.csv")

    //..... many other code unrelated

    val data = rdd.map{ s =>
      val a = s.split(",")
      for (i <- 1 to a(3).toInt) { //for (i<-1 to 100) {
        a(2) = (a(2).toFloat * (1 + a(4).toFloat)).toString
        a(9) = i.toString
        if (a(2).toFloat>1000000000) {
          a(10) = "billionaire"
        }
    }
    a
    }


    print(data)

    spark.stop()
  }
}
```

The program works fine for most of the data, calculating the income after several years based on rate and start up. However, the input of string only has 9 ",", that means there is no a(10) and get Exception when there is a billionaire. I finish the debugging but find it is really inconvenient, since every time you need to upload your code to server and wait for a really really long time. Is there any other convenient way for spark debugging?

Comment: You can always test your code on spark-shell on the server

Comment: Or you can run it on local spark in standalone mode with the data for which its failing.
`spark.setMaster("local[*]")` would run it local mode if SPARK_HOME is correctly setup.